# oracle apex apex_item doesnt' show input item

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm building a classic report using in SQL Query apex_item:

```
SELECT || apex_item.text (32,
              entity_type,
              80,
              100,
              'style="width:170px"',
              'f32_' || LPAD (ROWNUM, 4, '0')
             )
    from emp
```

but when I run the page I don't see text item, instead html code, for example

```
<input type="text" name="f32" size="80" maxlength="100" value="" style="width:170px" id="f32_9901" />
<input type="text" name="f32" size="80" maxlength="100" value="" style="width:170px" id="f32_9901" />
```

I cannot understand what is wrong on my page in order to display input item; some helps?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If using APEX 5.0 or later, look for the column property **Escape special characters** under **Security** and set it to **No**.

On older APEX versions change the column **Display As** property to the one that end in **"...(do not escape special characters)"** (I don't have older version so can't remember the exact name).

Comment: Hi, I've set Escape special characters  No and now I see text input. Thanks!